# I had a ESTA, then applied for a US B-1/B-2 visa and was denied. Is my ESTA now void?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

I only wanted to visit my son and new grandson and spend time with them. I feel now I cannot go an visit. The woman at the embassy did not even ask for any documents; she just basically said no, and shrugged her shoulders.

Comment: Why were you refused?

Comment: Why did you apply for a B1/B2 visa in the first place when you are a visa-free national **and** had a valid ESTA? Were you planning to stay for more than 3 months?